# Create JavaVM with bundled resources

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I have to edit the original post because it was misleading. I have an application that creates a JavaVM with JNI. It is written in C++ with QT5 framework. I have no problems creating the jvm and calling functions from my java application if I provide the .class and .jar files next to the .exe file of my application.
Now since java applications can be decompiled my company's standards does not allow me to distribute this application to local users because it does contain critical passwords they can't access. Like this from the security collegues I got a response that they're happy with the application IF i bundle the java sources in the .exe file. The QT Resource files would be awesome for this job which I have defined as follows:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/javaApplication">
        <file>resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.class</file>
        <file>resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.jar</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and thus makes me able to access the files with the following paths:

```
:/javaApplication/resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.class
:/javaApplication/resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.jar
```

Nice and smooth, but these paths doesn't seem to work with JavaVMArgs:

```
// Does work but violates security policies:
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:/Users/johorvat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld/build/classes/helloworld/HelloWorld.class;C:/Users/johorvat/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld/dist/HelloWorld.jar";
// Does not work, sadly I try to achieve something like this:
options[1].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=:/javaApplication/resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.class;:/javaApplication/resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.jar";
```

How could I achieve to have the second variant up and running?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21536892/1329652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has little to do with Qt and can be simply rephrased as:

**Is there a way to pass the *contents* of class or jar files to a JVM without saving them explicitly on disk?**

[I've asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21536892/1329652). The answers are: it is possible, but not without loading a bit of code into the JVM first. So you may in fact do what you intended to do, by first starting your own loader, then passing it data e.g. via a local socket or a localhost network connection. Your data can also come from a native method, and you can certainly write a JNI DLL using Qt.

The Qt resource system is invisible to anything but your application. It doesn't make any sense that you're calling JVM or any other executable with arguments that are Qt-specific resource paths. The JVM doesn't know anything about those files, and won't ever know. Not unless you reimplement the Qt resource system in java, but even then you need those initial class files to be out there.

The Qt resources are simply zlib-compressed binary blobs that are trivial to extract from the compiled executable. They are not really "compiled" in any real sense. They practically are concatenated to the executable by leveraging the linker and compiler, but that's just an implementation detail.

> my company's standards does not allow me to distribute this application to local users because it does contain critical passwords they can't access

Everything can be decompiled, so it doesn't matter whether your passwords are in explicit java class files, or in qrc-obfuscated class files. The possible outcomes are identical.

To make life harder for reverse-engineers, all you can reasonably do is:

1. Protect the connection with SSL.
2. Verify the signature of the server, to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.
3. Bundle a scrambled private client key in the application executable. Use it instead of passwords. The server can have prior knowledge of the client key(s) allowed.
4. Statically link with your favorite SSL library.

If your scenario allows for it, you can protect the client key with a passphrase, and require the user to enter it every time they intend to connect to the server. That protects leaked executables from allowing a server break-in without having the passphrase.

That's about it, really.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In either way I think I'll go with an alternative approach like saving the files temporarily and once destructor is being called just delete them.

Comment: @Joey The biggest question is: do you need that java process at all? Is that something that can't be simply done in Qt? If you'd then statically compile your application against both Qt library and the runtime libraries, then it will be a much tougher nut to crack. You really don't want those passwords to be cleartext, though, and you don't want the connection to be unencrypted either. Those two are the easiest attack vectors, nobody would bother with disassembly if the connection has cleartext passwords!

Answer (score 0):

If `JNI_CreateJavaVM` is successful, then that's just the first step.  You've created the Java environment, but now you need to tell it what to do.

Your next steps would be something like this:

1) Load your class you want to use(e.g. HelloWorld )

2) Instantiate your class

3) Invoke a method on your class

```
 //step 1
 jclass HelloWorldClass = env->FindClass( "path/to/package/HellowWorld" ); 
 jobject helloWorldInst = NULL;
 if( HelloWorldClass != NULL )
 {
     //step 2 - use javah to determine your constructor/method signatures
     jmethodID helloWorldConstructorSignature = env->GetMethodID(env, HelloWorldClass, "<init>", "()V");
     helloWorldInst = env->NewObject(env, HelloWorldClass, helloWorldConstructorSignature);
 }
 //step 3 - Load your method's signature
 if( helloWorldInst != NULL )
 {
     jmethodID myMethodSignature = env->GetMethodID(env, HelloWorldClass, "myMethod", "()I" );
     int result = env->CallIntMethod( helloWorldInst, myMethodSignature );
 }
```

Comment: That's excellent thank you, but the main issue here is that I have to use the java class that's a Resource. For example I tried to add the .class file to my qrc file and that producd the following uri: -Djava.class.path=:/javaApplication/resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.class
Now if I try to find the class with this classpath "HelloWorld" I get the "error" message that class could not be found. Eg: jclass cls is 0.

Comment: @Joey Your classpath is invalid.  You need to point to the directory or jar file(s) your classes are stored in, just like you would if you were running code from the command line( e..g `java -classpath mystuff.jar MyStuff`, `java -classpath dir/where/my/classes/ MyStuff` )

Comment: I see. But still I can't add the .jar file standalone. Company policy. Either I compile it to the exe (QT Resource files) or stop the project. That's the reason I'm trying to make it work from resource files. Let's say I have a jar file in my qrc. The path to the resource jar is: :/javaApplication/resources/bytecodes/helloworld/HelloWorld.jar. I sadly still can't use it as classpath as you poionted out because there is no directory.

Comment: @Joey Can you deploy you java .class file in a directory with your exe? Java should assume the current working directory of the exe when its launched.  so if you put your classes in a folder with your exe named joe, try `-Djava.class.path=joe`.  Otherwise, I don't think you will be able to tell Java about your baked in Resources

Comment: I've updated my original post to make it more understandable. Yeah, well I can't give out those java files next to the application. The only possible rights I received is to compile them to the binary and use them like that.