# Is there a way to pass the contents of class/jar files to a JVM without saving them explicitly on disk?

Tags: java, jvm

Suppose that I want to prevent trivial disassembly of jar/class files.

A JVM is started from a C++ application that can descramble the jar/class files that are stored within its own executable. Is there a way of somehow streaming the contents of such files to a JVM without saving them on disk?

I'm looking for a solution on both windows and unix platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ClassLoader which gets its class data from anywhere.  You could even have it call native methods to obtain byte code for a class.  Have a look at URLClassLoader which is widely used, it can obtain it's classes from files on disk or the network or any supported URL.

Answer (score 1):

Think part what you're after is supplied by the `JarInputStream` class, [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html)

You'd need some custom class-loading behavior as well. May need to create a `Classloader` implementation that loads your classes as well if you go that route. It might be simpler to use the `URLClassloader` as well depending on your circumstances.